# when i implement third party library in android studio ,android studio show error in Task Failed with an exception in build

Tags: android, kotlin

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.irozon.sneaker:sneaker:2.0.0.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/irozon/sneaker/sneaker/2.0.0/sneaker-2.0.0.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/irozon/sneaker/sneaker/2.0.0/sneaker-2.0.0.pom
> Required by:
> project :app
> Could not find com.kaopiz:kprogresshud:1.2.0.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/kaopiz/kprogresshud/1.2.0/kprogresshud-1.2.0.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/kaopiz/kprogresshud/1.2.0/kprogresshud-1.2.0.pom
> Required by:
> project :app

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not blame of Android Studio, it's just Gradle can't find your declared dependency in your maven repositories.

That library stores in jitpack repository you not declared, just declare it in repositories block in your build.gradle in app module.

```
maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
```

or if you use Gradle kotlin DSL

```kotlin
maven(url = "https://jitpack.io")
```